# How set white color text in Modular Large Complication?

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch-complication

I can't set white text color for **body1TextProvider** and **body2TextProvider**. Only grey color available.

My code:

```
let modularLarge = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()
modularLarge.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: dateText.capitalized)
modularLarge.headerTextProvider.tintColor = self.tintColor

modularLarge.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: timeText)
modularLarge.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "00:00")

modularLarge.body1TextProvider.tintColor = self.whiteColor
modularLarge.body2TextProvider?.tintColor = self.whiteColor

handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(),complicationTemplate: modularLarge))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks to me as though there is either a bug, or some undocumented nuance to applying `tintColor` on `CLKSimpleTextProvider`.

As per documentation on `CLKSimpleTextProvider`'s `tintColor`:

> **tintColor**
>
> The tint color to use for text.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> On clock faces that support custom colors, this color is applied to the text in your text provider.
>
> <sub>Ref: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/clktextprovider/1627929-tintcolor</sub>

Now... after choosing the multi-color Modular watch face, we can observe that the `headerTextProvider.tintColor` works as documented and does apply the specified `UIColor`.
but...
`body1TextProvider.tintColor` and `body2TextProvider?.tintColor` does not work as documented as it does not apply the given `UIColor`.
Showing us that the documented behavior is not applied uniformly across all `textProvider`s.

---

### However...

I noticed that if you set the `CLKComplicationTemplate`'s `tintColor` to something, then `body1TextProvider` and `body2TextProvider` become white, even if you're trying to set another color like blue/yellow/etc.

Luckily, you want it white so simply `modularLarge.tintColor = .red` (or a `UIColor` matching your theme) will get you your white body texts.

---

### Summary:

No need to do the following (remove/keep, doesn't matter):

```
modularLarge.body1TextProvider.tintColor = self.whiteColor
modularLarge.body2TextProvider?.tintColor = self.whiteColor
```

Instead, do this before calling `handler`:

```
modularLarge.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

---

### Solution:

```
let modularLarge = CLKComplicationTemplateModularLargeStandardBody()    
modularLarge.tintColor = .red //do this

modularLarge.headerTextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: dateText.capitalized)
modularLarge.headerTextProvider.tintColor = self.tintColor

modularLarge.body1TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: timeText)
modularLarge.body2TextProvider = CLKSimpleTextProvider(text: "00:00")

handler(CLKComplicationTimelineEntry(date: Date(),complicationTemplate: modularLarge))
```